# How to see ARRAY with NODE JS soap

Tags: node.js, web-services, soap, nodes, node-modules

Hi need to make a WebService with nodejs, this is my first experience to make a SOAP with WSDL.

I use the library "node-wsdl" and i need to stamp a list of array in soap but now i receive a wrong response

I have this response from SOAP:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="http://localhost:3001/gateway">
   <soap:Body>
      <tns:listInvoicesResponse>
         <tns:0>
            <invoice_id>00000</invoice_id>
            <ipa_code>00000</ipa_code>
            <timing>Thu Jun 04 2015 16:35:46 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)</timing>
         </tns:0>
         <tns:1>
            <invoice_id>00001</invoice_id>
            <ipa_code>00001</ipa_code>
            <timing>Thu Jun 04 2015 16:41:29 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)</timing>
         </tns:1>
      </tns:listInvoicesResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But i need to have a response like this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="http://localhost:3001/gateway">
   <soap:Body>
      <tns:listInvoicesResponse>
<lists>
         <tns:0>
            <invoice_id>00000</invoice_id>
            <ipa_code>00000</ipa_code>
            <timing>Thu Jun 04 2015 16:35:46 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)</timing>
         </tns:0>
         <tns:1>
            <invoice_id>000</invoice_id>
            <ipa_code>00001</ipa_code>
            <timing>Thu Jun 04 2015 16:41:29 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)</timing>
         </tns:1>
</lists>
      </tns:listInvoicesResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I use this code for retrive info from a DB and print the result on XML like list

```
var myService = {
    ws: {
        gateway: {
            listInvoices: function(args, callback) {
                var ipa_code = args.ipaCode
                GetAllInvoice(ipa_code).then(result =>{
                    console.log(result)
                    result.map( el =>{
                   callback(result)
                    })
                })

            },

            // This is how to define an asynchronous function.
            getInvoice: function(args, callback) {
                // do some work

            }
        }
    }
};
```

And my wsdl is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="InvoiceGeneral" 
  targetNamespace="http://localhost:3001/gateway" 
  xmlns="http://localhost:3001/gateway" 
  xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" 
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding"
  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
  xmlns:tns="http://localhost:3001/gateway"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <wsdl:message name="listInvoicesRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="ipaCode" type="xs:string"/>
    <wsdl:part name="dateFrom" type="xs:string"/>
    <wsdl:part name="dateTo" type="xs:string"/>
    <wsdl:part name="Accepted_invoice" type="xs:string"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getInvoiceRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="ipaCode" type="xs:string"/>
    <wsdl:part name="refId" type="xs:string"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="listInvoicesResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="InvoiceList" type="tns:string"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getInvoiceResponse"> 
    <wsdl:part name="DocInvoice" type="xs:string"/>
    <wsdl:part name="descres" type="xs:string"/>
    <wsdl:part name="resultCode" type="xs:string"/>
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:portType name="gatewayP">
    <wsdl:operation name="listInvoices">
      <wsdl:input message="listInvoicesRequest"/>
      <wsdl:output message="listInvoicesResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getInvoice">
      <wsdl:input message="getInvoiceRequest"/>
      <wsdl:output message="getInvoiceResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>

  <wsdl:binding name="Gateways" type="gatewayP">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="listInvoices">
      <soap:operation soapAction="listInvoices"/>
      <wsdl:input><soap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="literal"/></wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output><soap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="literal"/></wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getInvoice">
      <soap:operation soapAction="getInvoice"/>
      <wsdl:input><soap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="literal"/></wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output><soap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" use="literal"/></wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>

  <wsdl:service name="ws">
    <wsdl:port binding="Gateways" name="gateway">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:3001/WebServices/InvoiceGeneral"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```